# Python: reading line from file with different types of variables

Tags: python, variables, types, try-except

Trying to analyze a 2 column (color number_of_occurances) .tsv file that has a heading line with a dictionary. Trying to skip the heading line in the most generic way possible (assume this to be by requiring the 2nd column to be of int type). The following is the best I've come up with, but seems like there has to be better:

```
filelist = []
color_dict = {}
with open('file1.tsv') as F:
    filelist = [line.strip('\n').split('\t') for line in F]
for item in filelist:
    try: #attempt to add values to existing dictionary entry
        x = color_dict[item[0]]
        x += int(item[1])
        color_dict[item[0]] = x
    except: #if color has not been observed yet (KeyError), or if non-convertable string(ValueError) create new entry
        try:
            color_dict[item[0]] = int(item[1])
        except(ValueError): #if item[1] can't convert to int
            pass
```

Seems like there should be a better way to handle the trys and exceptions.

File excerpt by request:

`color  Observed`
`green  15`
`gold   20`
`green  35`

Comment: It would be helpful to see a sample of the input file...

Comment: Why have you used `item[2]` instead of `item[1]`? Since splitting a `tab` delimited line on a tab will give 2 element list only.

Comment: Is there always one line of header?  If so, just put `next(F)` before your list comprehension.  (Of course I'm not sure you need the list comprehension at all because it seems that all you do is iterate over the list.)

Comment: @RohitJain Sorry, that was a typo, still fairly new to coding was thinking '2nd' column when i retyped code here from my script. item[1] is correct and should have been used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just skip the first element in the list by slicing your list as `[1:]` like this:

```
filelist = [line.strip('\n').split('\t') for line in F][1:]
```

Now, `fileList` won't at all contain the element for first line, i.e., the heading line.

Or, as pointed in comment by @StevenRumbalski, you can simply do `next(F, None)` before your *list comprehension* to avoid making a copy of your list, after first element like this:

```
with open('file1.tsv') as F:
    next(F, None)
    filelist = [line.strip('\n').split('\t') for line in F]
```

---

Also, it would be better if you use a `defaultdict` here.

Use it like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
color_dict = defaultdict(int)
```

And this way, you won't have to check for existence of `key`, before operating on it. So, you can simply do:

```
color_dict[item[0]] += int(item[1])
```

Comment: `next(F)` would be better than creating another copy of the list through slicing
, especially if the source file is large.

Comment: You mean: `[line.strip('\n').split('\t') for line in next(F)]`?

Comment: No.  As a line before the list comprehension.  It advances the iterator to the second line of the file.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski. Ah! Sure. Didn't knew that. Generator thing right? Will add it.

Comment: Yes.  Also, you'll want `+=` on the default dict assignment.

Comment: I just realized that `next(F)` may raise `StopIteration` on an empty file.  This can be fixed by changing it to `next(F, None)`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `defaultdict` in this case. Because, when each key is encountered for the first time, it is not already in the mapping; so an entry is automatically created.

```
 from collections import defaultdict
 color_dict = defaultdict(int)
 for item in filelist:
       color_dict[item[0]] += int(item[1])
```

Comment: Didn't know `defaultdict`, very nice!

Comment: `(int) item[2]` should be edited to `int(item[2])`.  (And the index is likely incorrect, so change that to `1`).